# Sliding Image in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiimageview, sliding

In my app I have a button. I would like to be able to tap that button and then have it move to a point on the screen. However, I would also like the image to slide to the point rather than just appearing there. Any way I could do this? At this point, my image goes where I need it to go, I just want it to slide there. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    imageView.center = CGPointMake(50, 50); // or wherever
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X 10.5 and later or iOS, look into Core Animation:
https://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/graphics-and-animation.html

Comment: @FilipRadelic, it says MacOSX or iOS

Comment: @Owl it was only saying OS X when I made that comment, but Kevin instantly edited his answer so there is no edit history. Also, Core Animation might be a bit of an overkill if all OP wants to do is slide a view.

Comment: @FilipRadelic, Ohh oka than you are right! :) but the other thing is I am convinced with this answer as it shows the bigger picture and not just giving the code to OP. If they will read the doc it is less likely that they will come here again unless they may keep asking question and the entire project is done over stackoverflow conversions lol

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is answered here, let me know if this does not help or is not exact enough.

[Move a UIImageView with an animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148987/move-a-uiimageview-with-an-animation)

good luck

Comment: That does indeed answer the question, but is an old and discouraged method since introduction of [block-based animation methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW108) in iOS 4.0

Comment: Your answer was very good but actually too exact haha. mprudhorn's answer was the best. Thanks for your help